# Use generated script from Oracle DataModeler to make database in phpmyadmin

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I designed a database which now I need to make. I wanted to use phpmyadmin, but I cant seem to find where I can insert the ddl generated from Oracle DataModeler in phpmyadmin, or maybe it isnt possible?

If its not possible, can you redirect me where I can insert my script to make a database? I'm making this for my class and they recommend using Oracle 11g database, but I cant seem to set it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data modeler doesn't have a 'live push' of generated SQL to a database. The main reason for this - this can be VERY destructive code. Alters, drops - all kinds of fun things.

You need to test that first.

So take your generated code and save it to a file or copy it, and then open it in your database tool of choice.

You say phpmyadmin - that's for MySQL. You should know that we don't have true support for MySQL in Oracle SQL Developer Data Modeler, just a generic ANSI SQL over a MySQL JDBC driver.

For full support of MySQL, you should use the MySQL Workbench - which will allow you to design and admin your MySQL databases.

*I'm making this for my class and they recommend using Oracle 11g database*

If you just need to design a schema/user, then you can get a copy of Oracle up and running very quickly. Either download and install Oracle Express Edition (XE) or get our Developer Day VirtualBox VM - which already has Oracle Database up and running.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up, so I dont waste time figuring it out. I downloaded Oracle Express Edition (XE) and set it up, works now.